# Cannot log in to Dockerized SSH daemon service using Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, docker, dockerfile

When I execute the example below from the [Docker website](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/), it works fine. As soon as I change it to `ubuntu:16.04`, however, the `screencast` password never works. It just keeps prompting to enter the correct password. Is there something different in `16.04` regarding the `chpasswd`?

```
# sshd
#
# VERSION               0.0.2

FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER Sven Dowideit <SvenDowideit@docker.com>

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN echo 'root:screencast' | chpasswd
RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin without-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

# SSH login fix. Otherwise user is kicked off after login
RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd

ENV NOTVISIBLE "in users profile"
RUN echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile

EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

Update: I also tried replacing the last line `CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]` with `RUN service ssh restart`, but it still doesn't work. Makes me curious about when to use `service ssh restart` versus `/usr/sbin/sshd -D`

Comment: Docker requires the main (pid 1) process to be in the foreground. The `-D` in `sshd` means "do not detach". If the process detaches/forks/daemonises the container will exit. `service ssh start` should not be used in a container, unless you happen to have an `init` that supports the `service` command as the main process.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, [if you are trying to ssh into a container, something might be wrong](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/06/23/docker-ssh-considered-evil/) (The `nsenter` command is now `docker exec` but the basic gist of the post still holds).

#### Ubuntu ssh config

Ubuntu 14:04 `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
root@1404:/# grep PermitRootLogin /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
PermitRootLogin without-password
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
```

The default Ubuntu 16:04 `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` contains an updated `PermitRootLogin` config.

```
root@1604:/# grep PermitRootLogin /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
```

The `sed` command `'s/PermitRootLogin without-password/PermitRootLogin yes/'` will only change the comment in the 16.04 config rather than the required config line.

#### Fix

Use `sed -ir 's/^\s*PermitRootLogin\s+.+/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

The regular expression breaks down to

```
^      # Start of line
\s*    # 0 or many white spaces
PermitRootLogin
\s+    # 1 or many white spaces
.+     # anything else on the line
```

So, replace any non commented lines starting with `PermitRootLogin *` with `PermitRootLogin yes`. You can also [contribute your updates back to Docker](https://github.com/docker/docker/tree/master/docs/examples).

Comment: I tried to do this, replacing that one line as you suggest. However, it still results in the same issue. Did you build and run the Dockerfile successfully?

Comment: This answer still led me in the right direction. I used `RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: The reason for the extended regex is to catch any config rather than a specific setting for `PermitRootLogin`

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem when pulling the latest version of Ubuntu (18.04). The original solution doesn't fix the problem as in this version, the keyword is prefixed with '#'. The following updated syntax will fix it whether you are using 14:04, 16:04 or 18:04:

```
sed -ir 's/^#*PermitRootLogin .*/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Comment: Works for 18.04 and 20.04